# How to run Tensorflow JS in Node Alpine Docker Container - Missing libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I want to run Tensorflow JS in a node docker image. I get errors about missing libraries.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine
```

package.json

```
"@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^4.0.0",
```

Some script

```
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs-node";
```

The error

```
Error: libc.musl-x86_64.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
findus    |     at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1239:18)
findus    |     at Object.nodeDevHook [as .node] (/app/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/hook.js:63:13)
findus    |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
findus    |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
findus    |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19)
findus    |     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
findus    |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
findus    |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:14)
findus    |     at Module._compile (/app/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:547:25)
findus    |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
findus    | [ERROR] 19:58:30 Error: libc.musl-x86_64.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So far I tried the node-alpine and the node-slim image, but couldn't get it to run. Somehow has an idea how to get the docker config to work with `@tensorflow/tfjs-node` package? Hint: The non-node package `@tensorflow/tfjs` works fine, but is really bad compared performance wise. Should I maybe try to create from a completely different image, ubuntu for example?

Comment: Try using the vanilla node image, not alpine/slim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, yeah in the end I got it working by using the base node image. I had problems that docker-compose didn't correctly rebuild the container after changing the `Dockerfile`, so make sure to also take care of that.

```
FROM node:16
```

This image has all required dependencies.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what type of computer are you working from? I want to find out if this is similar to another issue I've come across

Comment: @JenPerson  I'm on Ubuntu 22 (personal laptop) and run a docker container obviously.:D